# Speed up r loop string match (vector vs. data.frame)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, match, vectorization

I'm trying to optimize a loop in r that counts the number of string matches of each element in a vector regarding each row in a data frame. In small datasets it works pretty good (~15 min; 11 columns, 914 rows). However, it takes days for running in huge datasets (914 columns, 18.000 rows). Here's my extremely basic loop:

```
for (j in 1: dim(pddbnh)[1]){
  for (i in 1:dim(pidf)[1]){
    richa[i,j] <- length(pidf[i,][pidf[i,] == row.names(pddbnh)[j] ])
   }
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to optimize this loop using other approach (e.g. vectorization). Any solution would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Here's a small dataset. That's the fastest one

```
 df<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c("sp1", "sp2"),10,rep=TRUE)))
 vec<-c("sp1", "sp2")
 richa <- data.frame()

  for (j in 1:length(vec)){
    for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
     richa[i,j] <- length(df[i,][df[i,] == vec[j] ])
     }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I probably know how to do this. Please provide a minimal reproducible example for testing.

Comment: Thank you! Here are the two files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvksp7c1kerqjbq/pddbnh.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjt9shku0gjf03t/pidf.csv?dl=0

Comment: (Obviously you have not yet done a thorough search of SO, since there are many Q&A's about improving performance of for-loops.) Asking for `[` to process `[ pidf[i,] == row.names(pddbnh)[j] ]` would seem doomed to failure. The result of that argument will be either 0 or 1 after coercion (so errors regarding replacement having length zero should appear). Maybe you should explain what it is that you are actually attempting.

Comment: Actually, it works better than other functions (e.g. grep). I'm just trying to count the number of times a string (row.names(pddbnh)[j]) is found in each line from a dataframe (pidf[i,]).

Comment: Post a small example (... dropbox is not a friendly way to share data anymore). Maybe the example will demonstrate why a logical index wouldn't generate errors if it returned FALSE's.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted a small example (sorry about dropbox). I'm adding both strategies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method using `lapply` (see below for even faster):

```
richa <- lapply( X = vec, FUN = function(x) rowSums( df == x ) )
richa <- do.call( cbind, richa )
```

A quick `microbenchmark` on the small dataset you've provided shows this at about 10x faster than your `for` loop method.

Just to add, this could easily be multi-threaded as well for really big datasets, using either `parallel::mclapply` or `plyr::laply` (with `parallel = TRUE`). It takes a little extra work, but might be worthwhile for those 18000 x 914 datasets you've got.

EDIT TO ADD: since you've got a few for loops going there (and since I'm learning Rcpp, and keen to practice) here's an even faster solution using `Rcpp`. Here's the function definition (which needs to be compiled once):

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(' IntegerMatrix charCrossCheck( CharacterMatrix df,
                          CharacterVector vec ) {

              IntegerMatrix output( df.nrow(), vec.size() );

              for (int j=0; j < vec.size(); ++j ){
                  for (int i=0; i < df.nrow(); ++i ){
                      int count = 0;
                      for( int k=0; k < df.ncol(); k++ ){
                          if( df(i,k) == vec[j] ) {
                              count++;
                          }
                      }
                      output(i,j) = count;
                  }
              }
              return output;

              } ')
```

Then you can call that function with:

```
richa <- charCrossCheck( as.matrix(df), vec )
```

`Rcpp` is very fast here. Microbenchmark on your very small sample shows it more than 3x faster than my `lapply` solution above, and about 38x faster than your `for` loops in R.

Interestingly, expanding the input data out to a `df` size 4000x4000, and a `vec` of length 10, both the `Rcpp` and `lapply` methods complete the job in very similar times (3.4 and 3.9 seconds respectively). On a dataset the size you mention (18000 rows x 914 columns, with `vec` length 2), both solutions are well under 1 second. Not bad either way!

Comment: both methods are quite faster! That's amazing and helps me a lot. I'll try to figure out the details of both implementations. I'm surprised!